# keras sequential model for image data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

i'm trying to train a dense network for images.

the train set shape returns:

```
train_X.shape
(26032, 32, 32)
```

and the network architecture is:

```
def get_model(input_shape):
    model = Sequential([
    Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(input_shape[1],input_shape[2],1)),
    Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')]) 
    return model
```

but i get an error when i try to train it :

Error when checking input: expected dense_17_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (73257, 32, 32)

can u assist please?

Answer (score 0):

For this specific architecture, you don't need a 4th dimension. In `input_shape`, you won't need to add a `1`.

```
 input_shape=(input_shape[1], input_shape[2])
```

You will only need to do so for a CNN.

Comment: Could you comment on the pros or cons of rather not flattening the 32x32 image and using such a flattened array as input? (One I know of is the number of weights reduce from 32x32xunits to 32xunits)